# Dynamically generate bootstrap grid HTML from JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, dynamic-html

I am trying to generate an HTML from a JSON object. Please have a look at my required output HTML and JSON below

**Required generated HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col col-sm-5">Span 5</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-3">Span 3</div>
    <div class="col col-sm-2">
      <div class="col col-sm-12">Span 2</div>
      <div class="col col-sm-12">Span 2</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

**JSON**

```
    [
               {
                    "Name": "span5",
                    "RowSpan":2,
                    "ColSpan": 5
                },
                {
                    "Name": "span3",
                    "RowSpan": 2,
                    "ColSpan": 3
                },
                {
                    "Name": "span2",
                    "RowSpan": 1,
                    "ColSpan": 2
                },
                {
                    "Name": "span2",
                    "RowSpan": 1,
                    "ColSpan": 2
                }
   ]
```

The code which I tried is below, which is not working as expected, I am able to implement `colspan` but, I am not sure how do I implement `rowspan`.
The last `span2` cell should come below third `span2` cell and that way first and second cells should occupie two rows as their `rowspan` is 2

https://jsfiddle.net/v1mzn6bu/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="replica" class="row">

  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var replica = document.getElementById('replica');
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    replica.innerHTML += '<div class="col col-sm-' + json[i].ColSpan + '">' + json[i].Name + '</div>';
}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really need a RowSpan? You could just make an optional `Children` property and add a conditional nested for loop for them to keep the structure same as the required output.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to do the structure you want you'll need to nest two cols inside another one

I'ld advise you to make your JSON structure accordingly, something like

```
var json = [         {
                    "Name": "span5",
                    "ColSpan": 5
                },
                {
                    "Name": "span3",
                    "ColSpan": 3
                },
                {
                    "Name": "span2",
                    "ColSpan": 2,
                    "children":[
                      {
                          "Name": "span2",
                          "ColSpan": 12
                      },
                      {
                          "Name": "span2",
                          "ColSpan": 12
                      }
                    ]
                }
];
```

It's worth noting that you'll need a "children" attribute to make the smaller span2 divs on the right, so inside the javascript you'll need to navigate it (reduce function may help):

```
var replica = document.getElementById('replica');
var str  = "";
for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
    str += '<div class="col col-sm-' + json[i].ColSpan + '">' + (json[i].children ? 
  json[i].children.reduce((acc,child) =>(acc + '<div class="col col-sm-' + child.ColSpan +'">' + child.Name + '</div>'),"" ) 
  : json[i].Name) + '</div>';
}
replica.innerHTML = str;
```

I forked your JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/s4vtyek2/